# Wit.ai: the screen is stalled while importing application

Tags: import, zip, export, backup, wit.ai

I have a working Wit.Ai application, and want to export, then import it into another Wit.Ai account. I exported the application into a zip file. And there comes trouble: When trying to import the file back into the new account: "We are creating your instance. Please do not refresh" is displayed for several minutes, then, dissapears, without any success or failure message. And no new project is created...

The project I'm trying to import is not huge at all; the .zip file is 3KB, and, got only 4 files in the entities directory.

Does anybody have any suggestion, or workarounds?

Thanks in advance for any help...